# Comparing specific columns in 2 different files using R

Tags: r, sybase

I find myself having to do this very often -- compare specific columns from 2 different files. The columns, formats are the same, but the columns that need comparison have floating point/exponential format data, e.g. `0.0058104642437413175`, `-3.459017050577087E-4`, etc.

I'm currently using the below R code:

```
test <- read.csv("C:/VBG_TEST/testing/FILE_2010-06-16.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "|", quote="\"", dec=".")
prod <- read.csv("C:/VBG_PROD/testing/FILE_2010-06-16.txt", header = FALSE, sep = "|", quote="\"", dec=".")
sqldf("select sum(V10), sum(V15) from test")
sqldf("select sum(V10), sum(V15) from prod")
```

I read in the files, and sum the specific columns -- `V10`, `V15` and then observe the values. This way I can ignore very small differences in floating point data per row.

However, going forward, I would like to set a tolerance percent, ie. `if abs( (prod.V10 - test.V10)/prod.V10 ) > 0.01%`, and only print those row numbers that exceed this tolerance limit.

Also, if the data is not in the sane order, how can I do a comparison by specifying columns that will act like a composite primary key?

For e.g., if I did this in Sybase, I'd have written something like:

```
select A.*, B.* 
from tableA A, tableB B
where abs( (A.Col15-B.Col15)/A.Col15) ) > 0.01%
  and A.Col1 = B.Col1
  and A.Col4 = B.Col4
  and A.Col6 = B.Col6
```

If I try doing the same thing using `sqldf` in **R**, it does NOT work as the files contain **500K+** rows of data.

Can anyone point me to how I can do the above in R?

Many thanks,
Chapax.

Comment: can you elaborate on "the same thing" and "it does NOT work" please?

Comment: trying to run the Sybase type SQL in sqldf causes R to keep running for a very, very long time ... and that's why I said "it does NOT work".

Comment: you seem to have several questions here; maybe break them out?  I'm not sure if you are having trouble reading the values into a data.frame or if you're additionally looking for an answer assuming the data.frame's fully realized in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Au, this `sqldf` hurts my mind -- better use plain R capabilities than torture yourself with SQL:

```
which(abs(prod$V10-test$V10)/prod$V10>0.0001)
```

In a more general version:

```
which(abs(prod[,colTest]-test[,colTest])/prod[,colTest]>tolerance)
```

where `colTest` is an index of column that you want to test and `tolerance` is tolerance.

Comment: many thanks mbq ... can you also let me know how I can sort by col1, col2, etc? That will give me a complete solution.

Also, as an aside, can u suggest good books/tutorials for learning R? 
I seem to have lots of such data issues that I end up manually doing in Excel, and I think R will help tremendously in automating.

Thx a ton.

Comment: Check http://cran.r-project.org/manuals.html , especially R-introduction. You may also find something shorter in Contributed documentation. 
Sorting a vector is just `sort`, `order` returns the index vector of sorted vector, so it helps sorting data frames. R has a built-in documentation, issue `?sort` or `?order` to get more info and examples.
I would be grateful if you accept this answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know R but I'm suggesting this as a general advice. You should paginate your table and then use your query. I mean I think in general is not wise to execute specific comparison instructions over a table that big.