# R (64-bit on Windows): How to get around "cannot allocate vector of size 557.6 Mb" error in code

Tags: r, csv, difference

This is a follow-up to [my earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60021175/r-how-to-locate-and-compare-a-particular-element-between-two-csv-text-files/) about how to locate a compare a particular attribute between two text files.

Thanks to the accepted answer I got together below code which works (on my system) on smaller data sets:

```
library(tidyverse, data.table)

con1  <- file("file1.csv", open = "r")
con2  <- file("file2.csv", open = "r")

file1 <- select(read.csv(con1, sep = "|", fill = F, colClasses = "character"),
                PROFILE.ID, USERID)

setDT(file1)

file2 <- select(read.csv(con2, sep = "|", fill = F, colClasses = "character"),
                PROFILE.ID, USERID)

setDT(file2)

full_join(file1, file2, by = "USERID") %>%
  filter(is.na(PROFILE.ID.x) | is.na(PROFILE.ID.y) |
                PROFILE.ID.x != PROFILE.ID.y)

close(con1)
close(con2)
```

**The problem:**
When R starts processing the full_join function, it eventually stops with the error `cannot allocate vector of size 557.6 Mb`.

**The environment:**
This is a 64-bit R v.3.6.2 on a Windows 10 OS and memory.limit() returns 16222. I don't have any other objects loaded in R except what is loaded by above code.

**Probable cause:**
The problem probably comes from that the two CSV files have about 120K rows and 83 columns each.

**What I have tried so far but without resolving the issue:**

- Included the use of the select() function to remove the unnecessary columns.
- Included the use of data.table and setDT() to convert the data frames
  to data tables.
- Closed all apps that have a visible UI (Outlook, Google Chrome,
  Excel, etc).

Regardless of what I have tried the error always refers to "557.6 Mb". I cannot add more RAM to this machine at the moment as it is a company laptop.

**Question:**
Is there a way to load the files in chunks or some other way (in re-writing the code) to get around the error?

Comment: Check how many overlapping USERIDs there are.  What happens if you join the head(10000) of both tables?

Comment: thank you @mr.joshuagordon! I did that and did get some output without the process crashing. The output seemed to indicate that the process has an issue because some of the rows have a blank USERID. So I then added a line to first filter() the rows to only those where USERID is not blank, and it now seems to be working. That was a good tip so thank you for that.

Comment: If you're using `data.table`, then you should use the DT-friendly `merge` instead of `dplyr`'s join functions. It's not that the join functions are bad, but `data.table` tries very hard to be memory-efficient, and this includes non-deep-copy merges. Take a quick look at `?merge.data.table`. Long story short: `merge(file1, file2, by = "USERID", all = TRUE)[is.na(PROFILE.ID.x) | is.na(PROFILE.ID.y) | PROFILE.ID.x != PROFILE.ID.y,]`. If that doesn't work, then my next suggestion would be to move this to a database (or similar non-local, non-R solution).

Comment: good to know! thank you @r2evans.

Comment: (My answer in your previous question leaned towards `dplyr` because I saw `tidyverse` and I don't recall see a "large data" hint. While `dplyr` has many advantages, memory is not one of them, I think `data.table` wins that debate many times over.)

Comment: Note you are reading in all 83 columns when you only require 2. Although it doesn't seem to be a bottleneck for this problem, you'd be well advised to only read in the columns you need `file1 <- fread("file1.csv", select = c("PROFILE.ID", "USERID"))`

Comment: good point. Thank you @Hugh

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My first solution here was that to remove those rows from file1 and file2 where the USERID is blank.

This is not an ideal solution (considering that `merge` is probably more DT-friendly than the join functions in `dplyr`) as per comment made by @r2evans.

So a more effective solution would probably have been replacing the full_join with a merge, like so

merge(file1, file2, by = "USERID", all = TRUE)[is.na(PROFILE.ID.x) | is.na(PROFILE.ID.y) | PROFILE.ID.x != PROFILE.ID.y,]

But the first solution I tried that corrected the issue here was to add the lines `file1 <- filter(file1, USERID != "")` and `file2 <- filter(file2, USERID != "")` into the code.

In the end the code looked like this:

```
library(tidyverse, data.table)

con1  <- file("file1.csv", open = "r")
con2  <- file("file2.csv", open = "r")

file1 <- select(read.csv(con1, sep = "|", fill = F, colClasses = "character"),
                PROFILE.ID, USERID)

file1 <- filter(file1, USERID != "")
setDT(file1)

file2 <- select(read.csv(con2, sep = "|", fill = F, colClasses = "character"),
                PROFILE.ID, USERID)

file2 <- filter(file2, USERID != "")
setDT(file2)

full_join(file1, file2, by = "USERID") %>%
  filter(is.na(PROFILE.ID.x) | is.na(PROFILE.ID.y) |
                PROFILE.ID.x != PROFILE.ID.y)

close(con1)
close(con2)
```